# three.js: If enabling shadow maps for the renderer, setting alpha for the clear color no longer works

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am initializing the renderer with `alpha: true` and setting clearcolor this way:

```
renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF, 0.6);
```

When I turn on shadowmaps (`renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;`), the alpha setting has no effect (it's as if I set it to `1`).

I can get back the alpha background if I comment out the `shadowMapEnabled` line.

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm wondering if there is a workaround.

Comment: It is potentially possible that some part of the process involved with using self-shadowing for rendering the model could be writing `1` to the alpha channel. Hard to tell what it's doing.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle showing your problem? Everything is working as intended for me, see: http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/123/

Comment: @FalkThiele [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/125/). Indeed commenting/uncommenting `renderer.shadowMapEnabled=true` changes the alpha channel (here with r72dev). Seems to be an issue, haven't found any reported on github. Unless i missed anything you can open one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the three.js r.72 dev branch.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7124

Comment: Confirmed fixed (using code change mentioned in github discussion -- please update the PR so the rest of the world can get the fix). Many thanks. You're awesome!

Comment: Now in dev (r72) branch